# How to convert docx to pdf use java (korea)

Tags: pdf, apache-poi, docx

I try convert docx to pdf.

Docx file has korean
maybe you think BTS song's lyrics

Eg.
Friends
BTS
유난히도 반짝였던 서울!
처음 보는 또 다른 세상
땀에 잔뜩 밴 채 만난 넌
뭔가 이상했었던 아이
난 달에서, 넌 별에서
우리 대화는 숙제 같았지
하루는 베프, 하루는 웬수
I just wanna understand
Hello my alien
우린 서로의 mystery
그래서 더 특별한 걸까
언젠가 이 함성 멎을 때 stay, hey
내 옆에 함께 있어줘
영원히 계속 이곳에 stay, hey
네 작은 새끼손가락처럼
일곱 번의 여름과 추운 겨울보다
오래
수많은 약속과 추억들보다

this is my convering code.

```
  String k=null;
        OutputStream fileForPdf =null;
    try {

        String fileName=w;
        //Below Code is for .doc file
        if(fileName.endsWith(".doc"))
        {
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(
                    fileName));
            WordExtractor we=new WordExtractor(doc);
            k = we.getText();

            fileForPdf = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    p));
            we.close();
        }

        //Below Code for

        else if(fileName.endsWith(".docx"))
        {
            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(
                    fileName));
            // using XWPFWordExtractor Class
            XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
            k = we.getText();

            fileForPdf = new FileOutputStream(new File(p));
            we.close();
        }



        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileForPdf);

        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph(k));

        document.close();
        fileForPdf.close();
```

this code make pdf file But this file didn't have korea lyrics

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach to convert a .docx file to .pdf file.

https://simplesolution.dev/java-convert-docx-file-to-pdf-file-using-xdocreport/

```java
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class FileConverter {

    public void convertWordToPdf(String docxFileName, String pdfFileName) {
        try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(docxFileName);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFileName)) {
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            // Convert .docx file to .pdf file
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, outputStream, options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
String docxFileName = "D:\\SimpleSolution\\Data\\Document.docx";
String pdfFileName = "D:\\SimpleSolution\\Data\\Document.pdf";

FileConverter fileConverter = new FileConverter();
fileConverter.convertWordToPdf(docxFileName, pdfFileName);
```

Comment: Thank comment but your code make empty pdf file.